# awk: illegal reference to array a

Tags: awk

I am trying to use this awk command:

```
awk -F: '
FILENAME==ARGV[1] { 
    a[FNR]=$1
}
FILENAME==ARGV[2] { 
    for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++) { 
        if(match($0,a[i])) { 
            print a[i],$1
        }
    }
}' 16.passwd 16.group | sort
```

But got:

```
awk: line 1: illegal reference to array a
```

Comment: I also had this problem for `if (!a) …`, which is essentially the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is this:

```
length(a)
```

Using length(array) to get the number of elements in an array is a GNU awk extension and apparently you aren't using GNU awk. Change:

```
for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)
```

to

```
for(i=1;i in a;i++)
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. It works after I change to for(i=1;i in a;i++). BTW, How do I know if my system (Ubuntu 12.04) is using GNU awk?

Comment: Indeed, POSIX defines `length` only for _strings_, not arrays. However, like Gawk, BSD Awk also implements it for arrays, and so does Mawk since v1.3.4 (whereas Mawk v1.3.3 and below resulted in the error seen by the OP).

Comment: P.S.: To complement this elegant solution for looping over a sequentially indexed array with one for counting any array's elements: `for (k in a) ++count`.

Answer (score 5):

I got this issue. Script worked on old server and stop to work on a new one.

Issue was that old server had 'gawk' installed, and new one has 'mawk', which does not support arrays.

I solved it by `sudo apt-get install gawk`.

Answer (score 1):

I did not see anything wrong with your script, as far as syntax goes. I saved your code in a file called *script.awk*, and executed:

```
awk -F: -f script.awk file1 file2
```

and did not see any error. Why don't you try the same: put your script in a separate file and invoke awk on it. If you still have the same problem, I suspect the problem might be in the data file.

#### Update

I cleaned up the code a little, the new version may be easier to read:

```
FNR==NR {a[FNR] = $1; next}

{
    for (i in a) {
        if (match($0, a[i])) {
            print a[i], $1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried nawk,   1 nawk -F: '
  2 FILENAME==ARGV[1] {
  3     a[FNR]=$1
  4 }
  5 FILENAME==ARGV[2] {
  6     for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++) {
  7         if(match($0,a[i])) {
  8             print a[i],$1
  9         }
 10     }
 11 }' 16.passwd 16.group | sort
got same problem: nawk: line 6: illegal reference to array a

Comment: It is very strange.If I am trying to use one line awk command, I got "awk: line 6: illegal reference to array a" error.But if I use the script.awk , then perform awk -F: -f script.awk 16.passwd 16.group. It works. Can anyone help me out of here? Thanks

Comment: It probably has something to do with quoting and the shell.

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with quoting and the shell, it's using a GNU awk extension when not using GNU awk.

Comment: How can I put $1,$3,$4 from in an array? awk -F: 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[FNR]=$1};FILENAME==ARGV[2]{for(i=1;i in a;i++){if(match($0,a[i])){print a[i],$1}}}' file1 file2