# Bash scripting, read two files line by line

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to print the first value (in file2) greater than a value of file1. To achieve that, I have the following code:

```
file1="valueA.txt"
file2="valueB.txt"
     
while IFS= read -r line
  do
  printf '%s \n' "$line" 
  while IFS= read line1 && (( $(echo "$line > $line1" |bc -l ) ));
     do 
     printf '%s \n' "$line1" 
     done <"$file2"
                    
     done <"$file1"
```

Here is an example for valueA.txt:

```
6.40693
14.2077
14.2829
50.7346
```

Here is an example for valueB.txt:

```
5.89669
28.4962
35.7508
36.2576
43.2666
93.3357
102.845
106.821
115.623
```

My code is expected to do this:

- print the first value of valueA.txt: "6.40693"
- print the first value greater than 6.40693 in valueB.txt: "28.4962"
- print the second value of valueA.txt: "14.2077"
- print the first value greater than 14.2077 in valueB.txt: "28.4962"

and so on.

However, I'm not getting any result inside the second While loop.

Comment: You should use `awk` for this, not `bash`.

Comment: This is really unclear to me. Please state your objectives as clearly as you can, with as much detail as necessary to explain your intended result, including examples of your desired output.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to accomplish. Please provide the expected output

Comment: Do you want the first value that's greater than *any* value in file 1, or the first value that's greater than its *corresponding* value in file 1?

Comment: I would like to read values in file1 and for each value v in file1, I would like to get the first value that is greater than v in file2

Comment: @ABM, you mean you want to first get minimum value out of all values of valuesA.txt? And then get very first value from valueB.txt which is greater than that value? Kindly confirm it once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 No, for each value vA in valueA.txt, I want to get its corresponding first value vB in valueB.txt so as vB >=vA

Comment: @ABM, sorry not clear, could you please do update your samples with correct ones and please keep samples small, kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: For example, for the first value of valueA.txt (6.40693), the first value greater than 6.40693 in valueB.txt is 28.4962. Then, I determine for remaining values of valueA.txt

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I reduced my samples in my post. I provided and example describing what I want in my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**with `awk`**

Input files are always sorted. You can modify the `print` statements as you wish, I print more to demonstrate how it works (and you have not added yet the exact sample output). Variable `resume` is used to ensure time complexity remains linear to file length. Usage: `awk -f tst.awk file2 file1`.

```
> cat tst.awk
BEGIN { resume=1 }
NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
{ 
    for (i=resume;i in a;i++) {
        print("i=" i)
        if (a[i]>$0) { print "First number found >=", $0, "is",a[i]
            resume=i
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**Testing:**

```
> cat file1
6.40693 
14.2077 
14.2829 
50.7346 
100000
```

I have added a final number greater than all numbers, it prints nothing for it.

```
> cat file2
5.89669
28.4962
35.7508
36.2576
43.2666
93.3357
102.845
106.821
115.623
```

.

```
> awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
i=1
i=2
First number found >= 6.40693  : 28.4962
i=2
First number found >= 14.2077  : 28.4962
i=2
First number found >= 14.2829  : 28.4962
i=2
i=3
i=4
i=5
i=6
First number found >= 50.7346  : 93.3357
i=6
i=7
i=8
i=9
```

Comment: it solves my problem. I modify this `for (i=resume;i<=length(a);i++)`  to `for (i=resume;i in a;i++)`

Comment: @ABM Why?  (this was my initial version)

Comment: it because I'm not using GNU awk. same issue as in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921493/awk-illegal-reference-to-array-a])

Comment: very well! I also revert this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what you want: read lines from the 2 files simultaneously:

```sh
while read -r a <&3 && read -r b <&4; do
    if [[ $(bc -l <<< "$a > $b") == 0 ]]; then
        printf "%f\n" "$b"
        break
    fi
done 3<valueA.txt 4<valueB.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to get the minimum value of file 1, then use `awk` again to get the first value greater than that minimum.

```
min_file1=$(awk 'NR == 1 { smallest=$1 }; NR > 2 && $1 < smallest { smallest=$1 }; END {print smallest}' file1)
awk -v x=$min_file1 '$1 > x {print $1; exit}' file2
```

Comment: Hello Sir,IMHO by code shouldn't it be maximum value of file1? I apologies if I missed something here.

Comment: Yeah, I got it backwards. You want the minimum, but the code is computing the maximum.

Comment: yeah, it should be maximum value from file1 as per OP IMHO, you need not to change code, only a  word :)

Comment: "first value greater than **a** value". I think that means you want the smallest value from the first file.

Comment: oh ok even I am confused by OP's this line now :)